# Less CPU utilization on APP Server with increase in user load on Linux

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

When we try doing lesser userload test say for an instance 30 users using 1 app server we get 73 % utilization of CPU whereas when we increase the userload to 150 users distributed with 5 app servers the CPU utilization is 68%. Could someone help me to better understand the situation and any suggestion on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: This question is likely better suited to StackOverflow, and would benefit from a _lot_ of additional detail... We know nothing about the inner workings of your "_app server_", or the physical system you're running the test on (core count?) ... are the "_73%_" and "_68%_" figures a total system CPU time, or one-core CPU time? (as is often used by Linux - i.e: quad core can go up to 400%)

Comment: The APP servers we are using is a VM. 73% and 68% is the total CPU time for which the user CPU has taken 67.61% and the system CPU is 1.45%

Answer (score 0):

When you add tasks but the utilization of a resource doesn't increase,
this means that this resource (or the computer) is saturated.

In fact, adding more tasks to fight over the available resources will
usually just slow down the total throughput. It will also increase
the amount of process-switching, perhaps over-burden the RAM etc,
depending upon your computer's hardware architecture.

A computer is a complex machine, with a limited number of resources
such as CPU, disk, memory, memory bus and more, each of which can
become saturated and become a bottleneck.

For example, CPU optimization is maximal when the OS can allocate a
process per CPU core. Even if a CPU is multi-threaded, it's more
efficient not to multi-thread, since then the throughput of this CPU core
is reduced.

To get a better CPU utilization figure, you might actually need to
*reduce* the number of tasks. But this also depends on what the tasks
are doing and the availability of other resources than the CPU.